# PHP debugging for the newbie or complete idiot who can't figure it out

Tags: php, debugging

I am a novice with PHP and don't know how to debug my file. Last year I took some PHP code someone else wrote and adapted it for my use and it worked. This hear I am trying to adapt it again and it isn't working. It is not putting the name and address into the CSV file like it did before, just the date.

I have search this forum and elsewhere for help and I just can't get anything going. I have downloaded Xampp, Phpstorm, and Xdebug and they all seem to need something else I don't have. I can't seem to figure out the settings to use. It seems to want either a web server, Docker, or Vagrant. How much stuff do I have to install.

I like the way Chrome will debug my Javascript file, breakpoints and displaying variables. I want the same for PHP. I am not running a server and don't have PHP, well sort of, I downloaded PHP but don't know how to set it up.

The only way I have to try my PHP file it is to upload it to my host and fill in my web page and see what results I get in the CSV file. I could post my PHP code here but that isn't the kind of help I am looking for, I want to figure it out. I just need breakpoints and variable values.

Comment: You may be better off trying to follow a tutorial on how to debug (what sounds like) a CLI application - don't know if it is any good ( I use Eclipse) but have a read of https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-a-php-cli-script.html.

Comment: You don't need anything more than what you've already downloaded. Xampp+Phpstorm will let you do what you're trying to do. Xampp already includes PHP and a web server, and you shouldn't need Docker or Vagrant just to debug a script. Phpstorm has some instructions for integrating Xampp. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installing-an-amp-package.html#integrating-xampp